# How do i run part of a python module only once?

Tags: python, object, module, pid-controller

I'm making a PID controller for an RC car for cruise control in python, and wanted to separate it into a module, so the code main code looks cleaner. I can do this, but the problem would be that i have to create an object once for the PID controller and set its constants, and the remaining part of the code should run every time the function is called

This is my code for the PID controller:

```
from simple_pid import PID

def PID(rpm_array1, target_speed):
    Kp = 80
    Ki = 60
    Kd = 0.01
    Kf = 180 / target_speed

    pid = PID(Kp, Ki, Kd)
    pid.sample_time = 0.05

    avg_rpm_rear = (rpm_array1[2]+rpm_array1[3])/2
    speed = (avg_rpm_rear/60)*0.355; 

    pid.setpoint = target_speed

    x = pid(speed)

    pid_output = x + (target_speed * Kf)
    if(pid_output>0):
        throttle_target = pid_output+1455

    if throttle_target >= 2500 :
        throttle_target = 2500
    elif throttle_target <= 1455 :
        throttle_target = 1455

    return throttle_target
```

And i would like to use it like this:

```
import PID_module

while True:
    target_throttle = PID_module.PID(rpm_array1, target_speed)
```

What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your problem but it sounds like you want to create a PID class and in the controller instantiate it once and reuse the same instance multiple times.

Comment: yes, thats about right. I think that the line pid = PID(Kp, Ki, Kd) would waste resources, if i have created it every time the code runs. normally i would simply do  pid = PID(Kp, Ki, Kd) and in a while loop continuosly run target_throttle = pid(target_speed) or whatever

Comment: you don't create a class object with `def`, you use `class`. You can then define methods/functions within the class that you would like to be able to call within that class. Check out (for instance) [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure if this is what you're after but hopefully this gives you some idea of how to solve your problem.

```py
class PID:
    def __init__(self, Kp, Ki, Kd):
        self.Kp = Kp
        self.Ki = Ki
        self.Kd = Kd

    def throttle_target(self, rpm_array, target_speed):
        Kf = 180/target_speed
        avg_rpm_rear = (rpm_array[2]+rpm_array[3])/2
        speed = (avg_rpm_rear/60)*0.355
        pid_output = speed + (target_speed * Kf)
        if (pid_output > 0):
            target_throttle = pid_output + 1455
        
        if (target_throttle >= 2500):
            target_throttle = 2500
        elif (target_throttle <= 1455):
            target_throttle = 1455
        return target_throttle
```

Run some test case:

```py
import numpy as np
pid = PID(80, 60, 0.01)
rpm_array = np.array([0,10,20,30,40,50])
target_speed = 50
x = pid.throttle_target(rpm_array, target_speed)
print(x)
```

This gives `1635.15`.